# jQuery select option last doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a button and list of options. The idea is that when user clicks the button the default option changes from disabled to max value. And oposite - if the input is not checked, the default is again disabled.
But the value returns undefined. If I change the first and thelast to numeric values, everything works fine. What's wrong?

```
<input class="input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="select-pot[]">
<select id="select" name="q-count[]">
<option disabled selected> -- choose -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>

jQuery(function(){  

    jQuery(".input").click(function(){      

        var thefirst = jQuery(this).next('#select option:first').val();
        var thelast = jQuery(this).next('#select option:last').val();

        if( jQuery(this).is(':checked') )               
            jQuery(this).next('#select').val(thelast);      
        else        
            jQuery(this).next('#select').val(thefirst);     
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.next()` gets the next sibling, so you need to get the select and use `.find()` or `.children()` afterwards:

```
var thefirst = jQuery(this).next('#select').find('option:first').val();
var thelast = jQuery(this).next('#select').find('option:last').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since IDs must be unique, there's no point in doing something like:

```
jQuery(this).next('#select option:first')
```

when

```
jQuery('#select option:first')
```

would suffice, plus `.next()` would fail here since it evaluates the siblings of an element and filters on anything you pass, but your filter is what would cause it to not match anything.

Instead, use:

```
jQuery(".input").click(function () {
    var thefirst = jQuery('#select option:first').val();
    var thelast = jQuery('#select option:last').val();
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) jQuery('#select').val(thelast);
    else jQuery('#select').val(thefirst);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6xbjc3js/)**

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla javascript alternative for future viewers

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input'), input;
    for (var i = 0; input = inputs[i]; i++) {
        input.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.nextElementSibling.lastElementChild.selected = e.target.checked;
            e.target.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.selected = !e.target.checked;
        }, false);
    }
})();
```

```html
<input class="input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="select-pot[]">
<select id="select" name="q-count[]">
    <option disabled selected>-- choose --</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```